# Getting rid of product of sequence sign

Tags: problem-solving

I am having trouble with equation containing product of sequence:

$$\frac {1}{2} = 1 - \frac {\prod \limits_{i=1} ^{n} (366 - i)}{365^n} $$

How can I convert the $\prod \limits_{i=1} ^{n} (366 - i)$ part of the equation so that I can solve the equation?

[The equation solved by wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F2%20%3D%201%20-%20%28product%20%28366%20-%20i%29%2C%20i%3D1..n%29%2F365%5En)

(corrected equation in edit)

Comment: Are you sure of the equation ? It seems that no integer $n$ would satisfy it.

Comment: Sorry, there was wrong start index in the equation :/

Comment: I assume you're working on the [Birthday Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Calculating_the_probability), which shows that for $n=23$, the probability exceeds $\frac{1}{2}$. There's no integer solution.

Comment: Yes, this is related to birthday problem indeed, but im not looking for the integer solution, the value that wolframalpha calculates ~ 22.7676903156182 is fine by me, how could I get to this on paper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can write

$$
\prod\limits_{i=0}^n (366 - i)= 366(366-1) \cdots (366 - n) = \frac{366!}{(366-n-1)!}
$$

So your equation becomes

$$
\frac{365^n}{2} = \frac{366!}{(366-n-1)!} = \frac{366!}{\Gamma(366-n)}
$$

Which you can solve perhaps by some numerical techniques.

By evaluating

$$
\frac{365^n\Gamma(366-n)}{2} = 366!
$$

I found (one) solution is between $n=67$ and $n=68$...